# Converting a List to an old-school array of doubles

Tags: arrays, memory, c++-cli, new-operator

I am working with a DLL for some hardware that requires old-school arrays as arguments. I'm using Visual C++ Express 2010.

For example, it might have

`bool DLLFunction(double* array1, double* array2, int array1length, int array2length);`

I'm trying to isolate all that inside a singleton class, so that outside the singleton everything uses Lists and Arrays. That means I have a bunch of wrapper functions that take Lists and then convert them to double[] to pass to the DLL.

As such, I've made the following helper function to convert a List to a double[]. The problem is that the pointer-to-double comes out of the function as undefined.

```
bool MySingleton::AdaptList(List<double> ^myList, double *myDouble) {

if(myDouble)
    delete(myDouble);

myDouble = new double[myList->Count];

for(int k=0; k<myList->Count; k++) {
    myDouble[k] = myList[k];
}
return true;
} // AdaptList from List to Double*
```

In my code, I do something like:

```
double *oldschool;
List<double>^ myList;
myList = gcnew List<double>;
// a bunch of myList.Add( ) calls to add the data

bool success = AdaptList(myList, oldschool);

// eventually, delete oldschool
```

Using the debugger, inside the AdaptList function, `oldschool` holds exactly what it needs. When AdaptList returns control, `oldschool` shows undefined.

Why did it go out of scope?

Thanks!

Comment: The above code is not C++, but rather C++CLI, a quite different language.  Fixing your tags for you.

Comment: Having never seen C++CLI, for a moment I thought that my knowledge of C++ had become too rusty, not recognizing `^`. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either pass a double pointer to the `MySingleton::AdaptList` member function:

```
bool MySingleton::AdaptList(List<double> ^myList, double **myDouble) {
  if(*myDouble) delete(*myDouble);
  *myDouble = new double[myList->Count];
  for(int k = 0; k < myList->Count; ++k) (*myDouble)[k] = myList[k];
  return true;
} // AdaptList from List to Double*
```

or a reference to a pointer:

```
bool MySingleton::AdaptList(List<double> ^myList, double *&myDouble) {
  if(myDouble) delete myDouble;
  myDouble = new double[myList->Count];
  for(int k = 0; k < myList->Count; ++k) myDouble[k] = myList[k];
  return true;
} // AdaptList from List to Double*
```

Reason: You were passing the 'myDouble' pointer by value and not by reference in member function `bool MySingleton::AdaptList`.

Comment: Oh, I see... so the function was making a local copy of the pointer, which I was then "new"ing, and which then went out of scope, leaving the original pointer untouched. This way, the pointer itself is passed by reference, so that the memory allocation applies to the original pointer. Do I have that right? Thanks!

Comment: @user3677542 Exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you need an unmanaged pointer to an array it is always worth considering if you can get one from [pin_ptr<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz8byfh.aspx).  It will temporarily pin the array in memory so it cannot be moved while the native code is using it.  Something like this:

```
  List<double>^ list = gcnew List<double>;
  //...
  pin_ptr<double> p = &list->ToArray()[0];
  NativeFunctionTakesDoublePointer(p);
```

You can't use it if the NativeFunction() stores the pointer since the array will be unpinned when the `p` variable goes out of scope.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. The documentation was unclear as to whether ToArray would make an Array, or an STL array, or an oldschool array of doubles. This worked well.  Also, I got to learn better about pinned and interior pointers -- when I learned this stuff, a pointer was a pointer! Thanks!

Comment: Note that this will not modify the contents of `list`, because `ToArray()` returns a new array independent of the list's contents.

Comment: There's no indication that this is necessary, his original code didn't do that either.  Otherwise very simply done by just creating the list from the array again, also a one-liner.

Comment: Hans is right, this is just what I needed. I keep the "real copy" of the data in the List, and only make the double[] to pass to the old DLL. Thanks again!